# Google sheets filter multiple columns using OR but returns AND result

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[google sheets image filter formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evOBX.png)

The formula I have tried is as seen in the image. =filter(A:A,(month(B:B)=11) + (month(C:C)=11) )

Anyone knows why this is returning the AND result instead of OR?

Answer (score 2):

It is not returning `AND` but an error in `MONTH(non-date)` makes the matching fails.

```
=filter(A:A,(IFERROR(month(B:B),)=11) + (IFERROR(month(C:C),)=11) )
```

Comment: This is it. Thanks!